# Android WebView LoadURL error in Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-studio-3.0

I am making a basic app for testing that displays a web page (and that's it).

But in MainActivity.java, loadURL gets a "can not resolve symbol" error and Atl+Enter does nothing.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("WEBSITE");
```

In MainActivity.xml:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And that's **all** the code I put in.

[image: errors]

Pretty sure these are the logs

```
BUILD FAILED in 14s

15 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 1 up-to-date
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\Simon\AndroidStudioProjects\Project7io\app\src\main\java\com\example\simon\project7io\MainActivity.java:19: error: <identifier> expected
myWebView.loadUrl("http://project7.io");
                 ^
C:\Users\Simon\AndroidStudioProjects\Project7io\app\src\main\java\com\example\simon\project7io\MainActivity.java:19: error: illegal start of type
myWebView.loadUrl("http://project7.io");
                  ^
2 errors

 FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

Comment: Are u importing the right one - import android.webkit.WebView; ?

Comment: Yep. it's imported. still not working, I added in the errors

Comment: Can u paste the error from logcat instead of image. As image is not seen complete.

Comment: done. how is that?

Comment: Yes, the google tutorial on webView...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");
    }
}
```

You should be calling loadUrl method inside onCreate()

Comment: nope. same errors... here is a look at the code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ihokw_CXnUvgzFGtQhIt03ej11lNWyds/view?usp=sharing

Comment: error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KKCQ1VFx7KlwGVPWd2H4Gd07kKu9Y6TG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated the code - add super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); as done above.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U0o5fsKGASw7otMKfOKZOTxNGapEksgf/view?usp=sharing